# Creating a multi-player card game in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiplayer, actioncable, blackjack

I'm currently working on creating a Blackjack game using Ruby on Rails (Ruby version 2.7.2, Rails version 6.1.3) for a class. My teammates and I are hoping to soon convert the game from the current single-player mode (1 player vs an automated dealer) to multi-player. I haven't used Ruby on Rails before this class, and have very limited knowledge on supporting multi-player. I've found some posts on stack overflow from years ago in which WebSockets are commonly recommended as a solution, and [Action Cable](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) was specifically recommended.

Given that the majority of information that I've found on this topic is older and possibly out-dated, I was hoping to know if WebSockets are still the best solution for multi-player capabilities, and if so, is Action Cable the best available option for beginners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wouldn't normally accept questions that ask for a general opinion - as you get a lot of conflicting opinions!

I would encourage you to take a look at [Hotwire](https://hotwire.dev) which is recently released from the guys at Basecamp and works very nicely with Rails.

In essence, you need functionality that will update the state of the various objects without needing a full page reload/refresh e.g. if player A doubles down, all other players should see that reflected on their screen without reloading. Hotwire and the associated Stimulus and Turbo libraries enables this.